# CoffeeScript and MapBox: PopUps Display but do not Open

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, mapbox

I have a Rails app that displays a MapBox map with popups, but the popups are not opening as I expect. 
My CoffeeScript code is:

```
$ -> map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapcode').setView([40, -100], 5)

$.ajax
dataType: 'text'
url: '/places.json'
 success: (data) ->
 geojson = $.parseJSON(data)
 map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)

# add custom popups to each marker
$ -> map.featureLayer.on 'layeradd', (e) $ ->
  marker = e.layer
  properties = marker.feature.properties

  # create custom popup
  popupContent =  '<div>' +
                    '<h3>' + properties.name + '</h3>' +
                    '<p>' + properties.city + '</p>' +
                  '</div>'

  # http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
$ ->  marker.bindPopup popupContent,
    closeButton: true
    minWidth: 80
  maxWidth: 250
```

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ ->` is a shorthand to register a callback for Jquery's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. In your code you register three callback independently of each other. Each variable that you declare within these callback will only live there. Hence, when you call `marker.bindPopup()` you shouldn't have access to the `marker` variable that was declared in a different closure. 
Make sure that `marker` is accessible within all your callbacks / closures. How about you register the `bindPopup` callback in the in `layerAdd` handler? Make sure you indentation is set right.

Also, why not call `$ ->` only once?

```
$ -> 
  map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapcode').setView([40, -100], 5)

  $.ajax
    dataType: 'text'
    url: '/places.json'
    success: (data) ->
      geojson = $.parseJSON(data)
      map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)

   # add custom popups to each marker
   map.featureLayer.on 'layeradd', (e) $ ->
     marker = e.layer
     properties = marker.feature.properties

     # create custom popup
     popupContent =  '<div>' +
                '<h3>' + properties.name + '</h3>' +
                '<p>' + properties.city + '</p>' +
              '</div>'

     # http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
     marker.bindPopup popupContent,
       closeButton: true
       minWidth: 80
       maxWidth: 250
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Maybe the view is where I'm going wrong - currently, I have: '<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapcode')
    .setView([40, -100], 4)
    var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL(place.id + 'json')
    .addTo(map);
</script>'

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your web console of the Chrome or Firefox dev tools? Have you pause on exception enabled? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions

Comment: I get an error message _Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined_ that is coming from the following: '    map.featureLayer.on 'layeradd', (e) ->
      marker = e.layer
      properties = marker.feature.properties

      # create custom popup
      popupContent =  '<div>' +
                        '<h3>' + properties.name + '</h3>' +
                        '<p>' + properties.city + '</p>' +
                      '</div>'

      # http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
 marker.bindPopup popupContent,
        closeButton: true
        minWidth: 80
   maxWidth: 250'

Comment: Do you get the Reference Error with my or your code? Can you create a JS fiddle or Codepen? I think my code is ok, but this is really hard to debug remotely.

Comment: I get the Reference Error with your code and with the CoffeeScript here: http://jsfiddle.net/kongzi/6mneqx2a/

Comment: I look at the fiddle and corrected some of the indentation. You have to be very careful with the right indentation in Coffeescript, since it has a Syntactic meaning. Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mneqx2a/5/
You still won't see much, but that has to do with the fact that "/places.json" can not be loaded from the Fiddle. Consider entering the full URL.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Always be careful with your indentation when using Coffeescript.